# How do I extract any number of digits after the decimal point of a Float and convert it to a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically, I have a `Float`, for example: 3.511054256.

How can I extract `n` number of digits after the decimal point?

i.e. I'd like to retrieve 0.51, 0.511, 0.5110 or etc.

I know I can easily achieve something like this:

```
var temp: Float = 3.511054256
var aStr = String(format: "%f", temp)

var arr: [AnyObject] = aStr.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

var tempInt: Int = Int(arr.last as! String)!
```

However, this gives me `511054`. I'd like the option of retrieving any number of digits past the decimal point easily.

For a task I'm doing, I only need to retrieve the first 2 digits after the decimal point, but less restriction would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the number of decimal digits, say `N`, in your format specifier as `%.Nf`, e.g., for `5` decimal digits, `%.5f`.

```
let temp: Float = 3.511054256
let aStr = String(format: "%.5f", temp).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last ?? "Unexpected"
print(aStr) // 51105
```

---

Alternatively, for a more dynamic usage, make use of an `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
/* Use NSNumberFormatter to extract specific number
   of decimal digits from your float  */
func getFractionDigitsFrom(num: Float, inout withFormatter f: NSNumberFormatter,
        forNumDigits numDigits: Int) -> String {
    f.maximumFractionDigits = numDigits
    f.minimumFractionDigits = numDigits
    let localeDecSep = f.decimalSeparator
    return f.stringFromNumber(num)?.componentsSeparatedByString(localeDecSep).last ?? "Unexpected"
}

/* Example usage */
var temp: Float = 3.511054256
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
let aStr = getFractionDigitsFrom(temp, withFormatter: &formatter, forNumDigits: 5)
print(aStr) // 51105
```

---

Note that both solutions above will perform rounding; e.g., if `var temp: Float = 3.519`, then asking for `2` decimal digits will produce `"52"`. If you really intend to treat your float `temp` purely as a `String` (with no rounding whatsoever), you could solve this using just `String` methods, e.g.

```
/* Just treat input as a string with known format rather than a number */
func getFractionDigitsFrom(num: Float, forNumDigits numDigits: Int) -> String {
    guard let foo = String(temp).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last
        where foo.characters.count >= numDigits else {
        return "Invalid input" // or return nil, for '-> String?' return
    }
    return foo.substringWithRange(foo.startIndex..<foo.startIndex.advancedBy(numDigits))
}

/* Example usage */
let temp: Float = 3.5199
let aStr = getFractionDigitsFrom(temp, forNumDigits: 2) // 51
```